# What is the total number of spanning trees on all subsets of vertices in a complete graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

On a complete graph with $n$ vertices, I need to find the total number of spanning trees on every subset of vertices. The number of subsets in the graph is $2^n$. Cayley's formula $k^{k-2}$ then applies to each subset but I suppose I would need to know the number of vertices $v$ for each subset such that $k = n-v$.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. Do you want to know the sum of the number of spanning trees on all subgraph of the complete graph? Do you know the number of way to chose $k$ vertices among $n$? Since a subgraph of the complete graph is complete as-well, the answer should follow.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the lack of clarity. I might have changed the question since you responded. The subsets are not chosen, I need to consider every single one. I need to know the sum of the number of spanning trees on all subsets of vertices (or complete subgraphs as you suggest) of the complete graph.

Comment: Ok, then if you put $c(k)$ the number of way to chose $k$ vertices among $n$, then the answer to your question should be $\sum_{k=1}^{n}c(k)k^{k-2}$ right? Now $c(k)$ is a well-known function, $c(k)={n\choose k}={n! \over k!(n-k)!}$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). Does it answer your question?

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to count sum of the number of spanning trees for each subgraph of $K_n$, you need to:

1-  list all possible subgraphs

2- compute the number of spanning tree for each of these.

As you said, the number of spanning trees of the subgraphs of the complete tree depends only on the number of vertices chosen, since the subgraph are themselves complete, and is $k^{k-2}$ (where $k$ is the number of vertices of the subgraphs), except for $k=1$ where this number is $1$.

Then if you put $c(k)$ the number of way to chose $k$ vertices among $n$, then the answer to your question should be $\sum_{k=1}^{n}c(k)k^{k-2}$.

Now $c(k)$ is a well-known function, $c(k)={n\choose k}={n! \over k!(n-k)!}$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). So the answer is $ {n\choose 1} + \sum_{k=2}^{n}{k\choose n}k^{k-2}$.

See also https://oeis.org/A270593 for the first terms of this sequence and  context.